# Extracting 2 types of data from a cell and adding a new row

Tags: regex, text, split, google-sheets

I collect content of tweets in a google sheets cell and would like to split it into 2 separate cells:

- one with @user (anything starting with @) and
- one with #hashtag (any additional text shall be ignored).

The results shall create a new row in a different spreadsheet each time new tweets are received.
Any advice?

edit:
[example provided: how to go from sheet 1 to sheet2?](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dB_LQwlNe9Kxns9P619rg94h8gXf0erZEcJtWIDSEEI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you provide some example data of the tweets?

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. Just provided a sample sheet to illustrate.

Comment: The sheet has been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done very easily with regular expressions

Receiver of the tweet:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2, "@(\w+)")
```

hashtag:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2, "#(\w+)")
```

You could also extract multiple mentions or hashtags like this:

```
IF(
  ISERROR(FIND("#", B2:B)),
  "", 
  REGEXREPLACE(B2:B, "[^#]*(#[\w]+)[^#]*", "$1"))
```